# Resource not getting set from different app flavor

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cIoD5Uw5Jkut--qsJUX_hYBx13gbFNM2/view

See in above video

I have an app with 2 different flavors. I have added different app icons and some different images that is to be replaced. Icons , background images work fine for the other flavor but one image is not picked up from resources, it shows the default image only.

gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    fibodo {
        applicationId "com.fibodo.consumer"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "4.0.16"
    }

    jdsports {
        applicationId "com.fibodo.jdsports"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots in which its clear that preview is coming fine but when running the app it do not show respective logo

[image: fibodo debug]

[image: jdDebug]

[image: jd screenshot]

[image: fibodo screenshot]

Comment: please don't link to screenshots or videos. Just add your code here, you're more likely to get help that way.

Comment: have you set that image resource in java code too?

Comment: @fatemehfallahiarezoudar no

Comment: done this by adding condition in java code. But I want it to be done only from xml. is it possible? Please help

Comment: @ahuja007 have you had your resources in all resolutions(hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,...)?

Comment: For both flavor Resources are in xxhdpi

Comment: do you have any resources in src/main/res folder?

Comment: Yes. resource which is shown for both builds is there in main/res

Comment: ok I will prepare your answer with photos :)

Answer (score 0):

when you are using flavors you need to have flavors resoursec in separate folders, for axample if you have these two flavors :

```
productFlavors {
    fibodo {
        applicationId "com.fibodo.consumer"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "4.0.16"
    }

    jdsports {
        applicationId "com.fibodo.jdsports"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

you should have these folders :

[image: src folder]

add your flavor resources in their own folder and remove those resources from your main/res folder.

[image]

At this position every flavor first look at their res folders to find resources and if they couldn't find any, they will look at main/res folder, so if you put resources in separated folders they will not get mixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will definitely try

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, you are providing resources it needs for preview device selected in android studio but **somehow missing resources for your testing device**.

Say your preview device is `xhdpi` and emulator is `xxhdpi`, you are only providing resource for `xhdpi` so it is only working on preview but not in emulator.

There must have been this scenario or something similar, *the device is not finding the exact resource it needs, so it is using the default resource!*